# Xcode 5.1 std::string concatenation crash on iOS 5.1 devices in release builds

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, ios7.1, xcode5.1

When built with the latest XCode 5.1, iOS SDK 7.1 and LLVM 5.1, using libstdc++ for the C++ standard library, get crash in the std::string **append** method only on iOS 5.1 device.

Here's code example:

```
class TestClass
{
public:
    TestClass()
    {
        m_string = "string1";
    }

    void AppendString()
    {
        m_string += std::string("string2");
        std::string newString2 = m_string + "string3";
    }

private:
    string m_string;
};
```

App crashes in **AppendString()** method on this line:

```
        std::string newString2 = m_string + "string3";
```

If I remove this line `m_string += std::string("string2");` before creating **newString2**, code works fine.

Here's the stacktrace of crash:

```
#0  0x34c99fe8 in memcpy$VARIANT$CortexA8 ()
#1  0x3706f95a in std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned long) ()
#2  0x3706fbfa in std::string::reserve(unsigned long) ()
#3  0x3706fdb0 in std::string::append(char const*, unsigned long) ()
#4  0x000c0e5a in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*) [inlined] at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/basic_string.h:2121
#5  0x000c0e3c in TestClass::AppendString() at /Users/sergei/Documents/2_3/House of Fun/cpp/CasinoSceneManager.cpp:122
```

Have anybody experinced same crash? It happens only on devices with iOS 5.1 and 5.1.1 and only if app was compiled with **release** flag, not **debug**.

Thank you for the help.

---

One more note. 
If I change **Optimization level** to **None [-O0]** in **Code Generation** section in project settings, everything works fine. 
Maybe the problem has some connection to code optimization.

Comment: One more note. If I change this line `std::string newString2 = m_string + "string3"` to `std::string newString2 = std::string(m_string) + "string3"` code also works fine.

Comment: Is that the only code you're running or is the program doing something else? Sounds a bit like a problem with invalid objects.

Comment: It's just a test class to show the problem. In main loop of my iOS app I invoke it with this code : `TestClass* c = new TestClass; c->AppendString();`

Comment: And it's the entire class? If it is, the error most likely lies in the surrounding code, where *something* has undefined behaviour.

Comment: I can't show entire code because project is very big. All I wanted is to tell that if you have std::string variable as class field, and try to concatenate it with other string and assign result of concatenation to other std::string variable, app will crash, but only on iOS 5.1 devices.

Comment: The likely thing is that you have some kind of memory corruption somewhere. It's unrelated to, but is exposed by, the string concatenation. That's all the guessing that's possible with the provided information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple released a new GM seed for Xcode 5.1.1.  In the release notes they say they fixed a couple crashes:

> Fixed a compiled code crash on when targeting iOS 5.1.1. (16485980)!
>
> Fixed a compiled code crash when using ARC and C++. (16368824)

http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_5.1.1_gm_seed/release_notes_xcode_5.1.1_gm_seed.pdf

Comment: Yes, downloading Xcode 5.1.1 fixed the issue) Thank you